# How do I reset my Pokemon go acount?

Tags: pokemon-go

So I started an acount just for me and then after I started I found out how to start with pikachu so now I want to restart, but I have searched all over the game but could not find a way

Comment: - Go to: https://plus.google.com/apps
 - "Disconnect" Pokemon Go.

Answer (score 0):

When you first logged in I believe you had the option to use either your Pokemon Club credentials or your google account.  Because these are not connected in any way if you use the one your not using it should reset, allowing you to start over.

I haven't personally done this, but I think if you start a new google account that would also work.